# Генерация сетки судоку

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Вопрос: по какому принципу можно реализовать построение сетки судоку, именно вычеркивание цифр.

В правилах судоку говориться, что решение может быть только одним единственным. Данная задача я как понимаю решается полным перебором, так как если рандомно повычеркивать , по моим соображениям, можно напороться на сетку которую можно решить как минимум 2 способами. Например сетка 9 на 9 будет не так долго генерироваться но все же займет какое нибудь время, а если у нас сетка 25 на 25, да еще мы задаем под это все сложность.

Сложность - сколько мы оставляем на поле не вычеркнутых цифр, чем меньше цифр тем больше сложность.

Comment: Что такое вычеркивание цифр?

Comment: @sba, в данном случае речь ведется не о решении, а о генерации судоку. То есть берется готовая и полностью заполненная по всем правилам сетка судоку и дальше начинаем убирать (вычеркивание) цифры из нее пока не получим нужный вариант все еще удовлетворяющий условию единственного решения(а так же доп. критериям, если они есть).

Comment: @Alex Krass, перепутал с японским кроссвордом.

Comment: Вот вам хорошая статья о решении судоку: http://norvig.com/sudoku.html

Comment: @VladD по сути дела эта статья рассказывает как решать судоку, а не как правильно подготавливать сетку.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: Это да, но имея решалку, можно «легко» проверять единственность решения каждой данной сетки.

Comment: @VladD а если например я данный алгоритм вместе с генерацией сетки перепишу на Java android, не будет ли просадки в производительности? Или он будет думать не значительное время.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: Ну, Питон-то далеко не самый высокопроизводительный язык. Так что не должно, по идее.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве критерия удаления можно использовать минимально задействованное количество чисел на поле, необходимое для восстановления числа.
Т.е. сначала убирать более простые камни, а более изощрённые оставить на потом.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе судоку решается очень просто и быстро, даже один премьер-министр такую [программку написал](https://gitlab.com/disputant/sudoku/-/tree/master/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%80) :)

Поэтому можно, например, просто отбрасывать по одному случайному числу и проверять, однозначно ли решение, если нет - возврат (по сути ветвление с отсечением).

Но заранее заданная сложность может и не сработать - есть минимально необходимое количество чисел (насколько мне помнится, в обычном судоку - 17, но могу и ошибаться).